# Identifying date format

Tags: date

```
"2014-02-03T23:10:00Z"
```

I'm aware of what each of the numbers represents, but the T and Z throw me off. Does anyone know what type of date format this is? I'd rather use a native parser if I could find one.

Thanks

Comment: The `Z` is the timezone. "Z" mean Zulu or UTC.

Comment: They are fixed content.  The "T" is commonly used as a date/time separator and the "Z" means UTC.  You can account for them in a format as `@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"`.

Comment: (You can also have the format "read" the timezone using `@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"`.  "Z" in the date string will be read as UTC.)

Comment: @HotLicks The "Z" is not fixed and should not be treated as a literal. It should be parsed as the timezone. If the "Z" is quoted in the date format then the date will be treated as local time (or whatever timezone may be set on the formatter).

Comment: Right.  If the first of my examples above is used one must explicitly set the date formatter to UTC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be ISO 8601 format. RestKit has a parser for it. You should also be able to get `NSDateFormatter` to parse it.

Comment: There is no need for a special package -- NSDateFormatter can easily parse it.

Comment: @HotLicks You're right, I believe you can make NSDateFormatter parse it. I updated the answer to state that.

Comment: @Gavin There is no "should". `NSDateFormatter` "can" parse such dates.

Answer (score 1):

It is an ISO 8601 format (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).
T is Time delimeter while Z is used if time zone is UTC.

Answer (score 0):

"2014-02-03T23:10:00Z" is the ISO 8601 format (http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime)

the `T` represents the beginning of the time and the `Z` represents that the date is expressed in UTC (Coordinated Universal Time)

if you want to get the date with a specific format you could use `NSDateFormatter`

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd"];
NSString *stringDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@", stringDate); // 2014/03/03
```

If you need just a certain part of the date (e.g just the current month):

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM"];
NSInteger *monthNumber = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date] integerValue];
NSLog(@"%i", monthNumber); // 03
```

If you need the date in a specific language:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd' de 'MMMM' del 'yyyy"]; // You can add your own text between single quotes
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"es_ES"]];
NSString *stringDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@", stringDate); // 03 de febrero del 2014
```

Comment: None of the code you posted is relevant to the question.

Comment: @rmaddy He typed "I'd rather use a native parser if I could find one." so I explained him, in a simple way, how to use a native parser, although you could be right. ^^'

Comment: Yes, using `NSDateFormatter` to parse the ISO 8601 date string can done. All the code you posted is for converting some `NSDate` to various other string formats. None of that is relevant to parsing an ISO 8601 date string into an `NSDate`.